# How to trigger alert mail from SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, alert

I want to store few documents in document library and after upload the document I want to give expire data for each document. Now here I want some alert mail from SharePoint before the particular document will expire.

Please advice.

Comment: You should be able to create a Retention policy that starts an email that notifies a user based on metadata on the document

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom timer job to monitor expire dates in document library and send alert email to customers.

Guide to writing timer jobs in SharepPoint:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/a-complete-guide-to-writing-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2010/

MSDN tutorial "How to: Create a Web Application-Scoped Timer Job":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx

Comment: I don't have access for VS & InfoPath. Any other option like SharePoint Designer etc. I just saw we can use Reminder 365 web part for alert mail and its free I think.